# Three.js most complex model

Tags: three.js

I understand the best way to learn Three.js is to take examples apart. I can manipulate textured cubes and so forth, even extruded spline shapes but have yet to find an example to help model a [WC pan](https://www.replacementbathroom.co.uk/s-trap-low-level-wc-toilet-pan-white-4584-p.asp). Probably none exist but maybe an amalgamation - I don't really know where to start. I don't want to import models from say Google warehouse. Photos for texturing are OK but not suitable or useful here I think. Thanks for any pointers or other help.

[image: wc hilit nose]
<sub>(source: [glasier.hk](http://glasier.hk/image/wcnose.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three.js is not a modelling suite. Modelling is a huge subject with various dedicated programs like Blender, Maya, SketchUp, Mudbox etc each having it's own approach to creating geometries.

While you can technically create complex models with Three.js, it's not usually the best tool for it. Complex organic shapes are not easy to define mathematically or in code. The common way is to use some dedicated software to create models, export them to Three.js and set up, modify, light, tune materials and render them with Three.js.

You could theoretically create your own modelling tool using Three.js as the engine, though. Just as an example, here is one such tool, not based on Three.js but some other JS library and WebGL http://stephaneginier.com/sculptgl/ . It's entirely possible (and somewhat easy) to use that to sculpt a WC pan, save as OBJ and load it in Three.js using OBJLoader.

For a purely code-based approach, you could look into Constructive Solid Geometry modelling. There is a helper library for Three.js here http://www.chandlerprall.com/2011/12/constructive-solid-geometry-with-three-js/

Comment: Thanks for that. I want to do some research so I can briefly explain why I need to take a purely code-based approach. It is basically that I want to import only the basic data so that I can control the generation of someone else's model in my browser

Comment: I have ticked your answer as it did what I asked - provided pointers and other help. With what I have found and done I have opened another question here which is more specific.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363499/three-js-most-complex-model-sequel